# Replace everything after second occurrence with blank

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, char

I have a string a/b/c I want to replace everything after second occurrence of "/" to blank so my result should like this a/b
any help will be appreciated.

Here what i tired nothing is working

```
select reverse(left(reverse('a/b/c'), charindex('/', reverse('a/b/c')) -1))

SELECT SUBSTRING('a/b/c', 1, LEN('a/b/c') )

SELECT STUFF('a/b/c', charindex('/', 'a/b/c'), 2, '');

select CHARINDEX('/','a/b/c')

select right ('a/b/c', CHARINDEX('/','a/b/c')-1)
```

Comment: Could you provide some general SQL code towards that attempts you've made thus far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
SELECT LEFT('a/b/c',CHARINDEX('/','a/b/c',CHARINDEX('/','a/b/c')+1)-1)
```

The optional third parameter of `CHARINDEX` is the starting position, ie where in the string it should start looking for the desired character, by nesting another `CHARINDEX` function as the third parameter you can find the 2nd occurrence.  The `+1` is so it doesn't find the same `'/'` in the nested `CHARINDEX`, the `-1` is so it doesn't return the 2nd `'/'` as part of your result.

Comment: @user1570210 please click the checkmark next to this answer, so this question can be closed and used to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
select stuff('ashish jain',charindex('a','ashish jain',charindex('a','ashish jain')+1),1,'c')
```

It will replace 'a' with 'c' and return 'ashish jcin'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace rest of all occurrence characters except first occurrence.

```
declare @word varchar(500)='B-123, Address1-Address2-Address3'

select  CONCAT_WS('',left(@word,CHARINDEX('-',@word)), replace( substring(@word,CHARINDEX('-',@word)+1, len(@word)),'-',' '))
```